# How to send a keep-alive packet through websocket in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I want to send a

> "Keep alive from client"

message every 30 seconds for my websocket connection. Here's what the code that I have in my websocket initializer looks like:

```
ws = WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect 'wss://bitcoin.toshi.io/'

ws.on :message do |msg|
  rawJson = msg.data
  message_response = JSON.parse(rawJson)
end

ws.on :open do
  ws.send "{\"subscribe\":\"blocks\"}"
end

ws.on :close do |e|
  puts "WEBSOCKET HAS CLOSED #{e}"
  exit 1
end

ws.on :error do |e|
  puts "WEBSOCKET ERROR #{e}"
end
```

Without any sort of 'keep alive', the connect closes in about 45 seconds. How should I send the 'heart-beat' packet? It seems that the connection is closed by their server, not mine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping the WebSocket connection alive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218936/keeping-the-websocket-connection-alive)

Comment: It's similar, but a different issue. I'm having trouble specifically with toshi cutting the connection due to the lack of a response -- if they did not have this behavior, the connection would be solid. I can keep the connection alive if I periodically send a message that says I'm still listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Websocket Eventmachine Client](https://github.com/imanel/websocket-eventmachine-client) gem to send hearbeat:

```
require 'websocket-eventmachine-client'

EM.run do
  ws = WebSocket::EventMachine::Client.connect(:uri => 'wss://bitcoin.toshi.io/')
  puts ws.comm_inactivity_timeout
  ws.onopen do
    puts "Connected"
  end

  ws.onmessage do |msg, type|
    puts "Received message: #{msg}"
  end

  ws.onclose do |code, reason|
    puts "Disconnected with status code: #{code}"
  end

  EventMachine.add_periodic_timer(15) do
    ws.send "{}"
  end
end
```

You can setup timer for EventMachine with `EM::add_periodic_timer(interval_in_seconds)`, and then send your heartbeat with it.

Comment: I can get it to work up until including `EventMachine.next_tick`, I end up getting `error code 1002`. What do you mean when you say I can check the current time in `#next_tick`?

Comment: @Skull1234567 I fixed my answer. You actually should use `#add_periodic_timer` instead of `#next_tick` – now it works.

Comment: How to I close this connection and how do I stop the periodic timer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the auto-ping feature (its default and can't be turned off) if you're using [Iodine's](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) Websocket client:

```
require 'iodine/http'
# prevents the Iodine's server from running
Iodine.protocol = :timer
# starts Iodine while the script is still running
Iodine.force_start!
# set pinging to a 40 seconds interval.
Iodine::Http::Websockets.default_timeout = 40

settings = {}
# set's the #on_open event callback.
settings[:on_open] = Proc.new do
    write 'sending this connection string.'
end
# set's the #on_message(data) event callback.
settings[:on_message] = Proc.new { |data| puts "Received message: #{data}" }
# connects to the websocket
Iodine::Http.ws_connect 'ws://localhost:8080', settings
```

It's a fairly basic client, but also easy to manage.

**EDIT**

Iodine also includes some cookie and custom header's support, as now seen in [Iodine's documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/boazsegev/iodine/master/Iodine/Http/WebsocketClient#connect-class_method). So it's possible to use different authentication techniques (authentication headers or cookies).

Comment: Sorry if it is a newbie question, but how do I send a `ws.send "{\"subscribe\":\"blocks\"}"` type message with this once it has been connected?

Comment: @Skull1234567 - No worries. I updated my answer. You use the websocket object (event object) to send data or close the connection. You can find the documentation for the [Websocket event object here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/boazsegev/GRHttp/master/GRHttp/WSEvent).